# AWK adding a condition to a series of arguments

Tags: awk

I have the following file called an.txt:

```
Bank Fee        Monthly A/C Fee                         -8.50   31/03/2021
Eft-Pos Rutherford & Bond       4835********    8848   C        210331123119    -250.00 31/03/2021       
Payment Avery Johnson   Avery Johnso    592315  Labour  -131.60 31/03/2021
Bill Payment    Collins Tf      127 Driver      Crescent        I1600   50.00   31/03/2021
```

I have reconfigured the file with the following command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR>1 {split($7,a,"/") ; print (a[3]"-"a[2]"-"a[1]"\t"$6"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t""az")}' an.txt | head -n 4

2021-03-31  -8.50   Monthly A/C Fee         az
2021-03-31  -250.00 Rutherford & Bond   4835********    8848   C    az
2021-03-31  -131.60 Avery Johnson   Avery Johnso    592315  az
2021-03-31  50.00   Collins Tf  127 Driver  Crescent    az
```

I am trying to add "vi" at the back of the file for rows in column two larger than zero $2 > 0. The output should look like this (please note the vi at the end):

```
2021-03-31  -8.50   Monthly A/C Fee         az
2021-03-31  -250.00 Rutherford & Bond   4835********    8848   C    az
2021-03-31  -131.60 Avery Johnson   Avery Johnso    592315  az
2021-03-31  50.00   Collins Tf  127 Driver  Crescent    az  vi
```

How can I change the above command to achieve the desired result?

I have tried:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR>1 {split($7,a,"/") ; print (a[3]"-"a[2]"-"a[1]"\t"$6"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t""az")}"\t"$6>0{print "vi"}' an.txt | head -n 4
```

It is not giving the right output. How can this condition be added to the existing command?

Comment: Can you include output of `cat -te file an.txt` command in question

Comment: cat -te file an.txt | head -n 6
```cat: file: No such file or directory
Type^IDetails^IParticulars^ICode^IReference^IAmount^IDate^IForeignCurrencyAmount^IConversionCharge^M$
Bank Fee^IMonthly A/C Fee^I^I^I^I-8.50^I31/03/2021^I^I^M$
Eft-Pos^IRutherford & Bond^I4835********^I8848   C^I210331123119^I-250.00^I31/03/2021^I^I^M$
Payment^IAvery Johnson^IAvery Johnso^I592315^ILabour^I-131.60^I31/03/2021^I^I^M$
Bill Payment^ICollins Tf^I127 Driver^ICrescent^II1600^I50.00^I31/03/2021^I^I^M$
Bill Payment^IBecta Ltd^ITaylormallon^ILawns^IInv 1447^I46.00^I31/03/2021^I^I^M$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk '
BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
NR > 1 {
   split($7,a,"/")
   print a[3]"-"a[2]"-"a[1], $6, $2, $3, $4, "az" ($6 > 0 ? OFS "vi" : "")
}' file

2021-03-31  -8.50   Monthly A/C Fee         az
2021-03-31  -250.00 Rutherford & Bond   4835********    8848   C    az
2021-03-31  -131.60 Avery Johnson   Avery Johnso    592315  az
2021-03-31  50.00   Collins Tf  127 Driver  Crescent    az  vi
2021-03-31  46.00   Becta Ltd   Taylormallon    Lawns   az  vi
```

To get tabular output use:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR>1 {split($7,a,"/"); print a[3]"-"a[2]"-"a[1], $6, $2, $3, $4, "az" ($6 > 0 ? OFS "vi" : "")}' file | column -s $'\t' -t

2021-03-31  -8.50    Monthly A/C Fee    az
2021-03-31  -250.00  Rutherford & Bond  4835********  8848   C  az
2021-03-31  -131.60  Avery Johnson      Avery Johnso  592315    az
2021-03-31  50.00    Collins Tf         127 Driver    Crescent  az  vi
2021-03-31  46.00    Becta Ltd          Taylormallon  Lawns     az  vi
```

By using `($6 > 0 ? OFS "vi" : "")` we append a tab and `vi` when `$6` is greater than zero.

Comment: Thank you anubhava. What is the difference between tab seperated and tabular. Is there a tabular delimiter in awk?

Comment: Tabular (pertains to tables) output is just for display so that it is easier to read by humans.

Comment: There are a couple of things I am struggling to understand. Why the ? and OFS lacking a "\t" behind $6 > 0. And what does : "" do? Sorry really don't get the logic here.

Comment: It is because code is adding `OFS` or a tab only when it prints `vi` otherwise we will have trailing tab characters in each line that doesn't end with `vi`

Comment: So if $6 > 0 and that is true then OFS "vi" is printed, else : "". Is that correct? But then, why : ""

Comment: Just tested around. So I could also write ($6 > 0 ? "\t" "vi" : "\t"). This would also work.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier that `($6 > 0 ? "\t" "vi" : "\t")` will leave trailing tab characters in each line that doesn't end with `vi`.

Comment: @ChristianHick always avoid redundancy in your code, e.g.  `($6 > 0 ? "\t" "vi" : "\t")` = `"\t" ($6 > 0 ? "vi" : "")` = `OFS ($6 > 0 ? "vi" : "")`